# How Can An App Communicate With a Server and reflect updates immediatly?

Tags: android, web-services

hi this is just for knowledge. i will try to explain as much as i can what is my question. 
Usually i call on an Async Service every amount of time i.e updates on the server part for example are not reflected as soon as they change. whatsapp for example reflects the updates almost instantly. for example when a user is typing, it shows to the other user that he is typing.
In short what protocols do they use and how do they use it.

thank you.

Comment: As displayed  in wikipedia page of [WhatsApp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp#Technical), it uses [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp#Technical) protocol for such feature.

Comment: thank you, i will search about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What protocols do they use?

Application like Whats app,G-talk ,facebook etc they uses XMPP protocol  for IM services.

What is XMPP?

> The Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is an open
>   technology for real-time communication, using the Extensible Markup
>   Language (XML) as the base format for exchanging information. In
>   essence, XMPP provides a way to send small pieces of XML from one
>   entity to another in close to real time

As per latest version of [specifications](http://xmpp.org/) XMPP provides below services

> - Channel encryption [RFC3920]
> - Authentication [RFC3920]
> - Presence [RFC3921]
> - Contact lists [RFC3921]
> - One-to-one messaging [RFC3920]
> - Multi-party messaging [XEP-0045]
> - Notifications [XEP-0060]
> - Service discovery [XEP-0030]
> - Capabilities advertisement [XEP-0115]
> - Structured data forms [XEP-0004]
> - Workflow management [XEP-0050]
> - Peer-to-peer media sessions [XEP-0166]

This are the core services available in XMPP

Below are some Applications where XMPP can be used

> - Instant messaging
> - Groupchat
> - Gaming
> - Systems control
> - Geolocation
> - Middleware and cloud computing
> - Data syndication
> - Voice over IP (VoIP)
> - Identity services

Like HTTP XMPP also require server-client implementation

Below are some popular XMPP servers

> - Ejabberd
> - Openfire
> - Prosody
> - Tigase

You can find more information on xmpp server on this [link](https://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/)

Different platform has their different XMPP client library you can more information on this [link](https://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/)

If you want to implement XMPP client for android then you can use [Smack 4.1](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/) ,it is an open source XMPP client library written in java.

I have tried to list down basic feature of XMPP here but if you getting started with xmpp ,then there are lost of things  to learn , free to ask any doubt regarding XMPP I will try my best .

Thank you

> Note::
>         for the user who are still using aSmack should Upgrade to Smack 4.1 as aSmack has been deprecated!!

- aSmack Deprecation [Notice](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack)
- aSmack to Smack Upgrade [guide](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide)

Comment: hi thank you for your response its really useful, but the link you provided for aSmack says that aSmack is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you vary much for highlighting that portion I had worked with xmpp android client a while ago and used aSmack that time.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) service, as the GCM site says:

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) for Android is a service that allows you
>   to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device,
>   and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection...

This way you can inform from one client a status change, the backend then send the propper message to the desired clients and finally those clients app updates the status.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html